# How can I see logs from remote server during commit?

Tags: gitkraken

I have couple of hooks on my remote server repository performing build tasks like: npm i, npm build etc... so when I am pushing through console I can see output logs, it is very helpful in order to see if there are any errors in case of build failed for example, but in GitKraken there is simple preloader without logs. Can it be enabled somehow? 
Btw. SourceTree have this feature.

Answer (score 1):

**Output logs from hooks are not available in GitKraken.**

Official response from Axosoft on Twitter:

[image: Official response from Axosoft on Twitter]